# SQL join table need adjustment for query

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Query is working fine but I want to add that the genre should be drama only

```
Select writer.writer_name, book.book_genre,publisher.publisher_name 
from writer,book,publisher where  writer.writer_id=book.writer_id 
and publisher.publisher_id=book.publisher_id;
```

Comment: Please learn to use modern explicit `JOIN` operators instead of the ancient, outdated and fragile implicit joins in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: I'm a beginner, not sure what you mean. can you help using the current format.

Comment: @FidoDido the answer from partick artner below is correct. What @a_horse_with_no_name means is that basically you are getting a [cartesian product](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm) and then filtering it in the where.... where as it is much better to use the `join...on` syntax

Comment: lets assume each of your 3 tables has 10 entries. but only one author has written all 10 books and only one publisher was used (so the other publishers are in your DB but never published smth.) Your query fetches 10*10*10 = 1000 results and filters it. My answers query fetches 10 results and applies the where. LOTs less effort for the dbserver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a_horse_with_no_name means to use this:

```
Select 
  writer.writer_name, 
  book.book_genre,
  publisher.publisher_name 
from writer
join  book on writer.writer_id = book.writer_id
join  publisher on book.publisher_id = publisher.publisher_id

where book.book_genre = 'drama'
```

with explicit joins instead on misusing the `where` clause to join your tables. Adjust the '' around `'drama'` to suit your db.